# Protobuffs import from another project

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Project B is trying to import Project A proto file. Project B pom.xml has dependencies for Project A.

**ProjectB has person.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "projectA/src/main/proto/vehical.proto";

message Person {
   string name = 1;
   int32 age = 2;  
}
```

**Project A has vehical.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message car{
   string model= 1;
   int32 year= 2;  
}
```

while compilation getting below error

> [ERROR] C:\eclipseWorkSpace\TestProto\src\main\proto\person.proto [0:0]: projectA/src/main/proto/vehical.proto: File not found.
> person.proto: Import "projectA/src/main/proto/vehical.proto" was not found or had errors.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this experts?

Comment: Is "ProjectA" a subfolder of where person.proto exist? Likely your import path is incorrect

Comment: No its not a sub project. I have added projectA dependencies in pom.xml of projectB. Thanks @Quintium I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I just put `import "customer.proto";` in `person.proto` seems to solved my issue.